# Run a mass action on multiple records in a list view

Tags: lightning, custom-button, lightning-experience, list-view

According to the new release (Winter '17) is available [run mass action on multiples records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox), but anyone how do it?

All my list button aren't available in lightning experience

Comment: Are you referring to [this release note](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_list_views_custom_buttons.htm)?

Comment: Yes I'm referring to this release note

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**List View Buttons Not Available in LEX**

To Answer the statement "All my list button aren't available in lightning experience", any onclick javascript button that you have in salesforce classic will not appear in Lightning Experience.

Hence you will have to use custom visual-force buttons and standard SetControllers and recordSetVar to get the multiple selections from the list view page.. ( These buttons will appear only on List view page and not on recently viewed items list page )

Reference : [Check out the last example to over-ride list view button and mass actions.](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/09/take-the-first-steps-ways-you-can-replace-javascript-buttons.html)

This blog series also shows what are the best alternatives for onclick javascript buttons in salesforce. Lightning Actions are not supported in List view sections as of now.

**Mass Actions in VF pages**

Mass actions can be performed using apex controller as follows

```
public class selectedSizeWorkaround {
    ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
    public selectedSizeWorkaround(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        setCon = controller;
    }
    public integer getMySelectedSize() {
        return setCon.getSelected().size();
    }
    public integer getMyRecordsSize() {
        return setCon.getRecords().size();
    }
}
```

Reference : [Mass Actions using VF and Apex Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_massupdate.htm)

The **getSelected and getRecords** methods should return sObjects on which we should be able to make our DML operations or our use case scenarios.

AFAIK, i think this is what the release note mean in terms of custom buttons and mass actions in lightning experience.

> Remember those brilliant custom buttons that you created in Salesforce
>   Classic by using Visualforce? 
> With the ability to select multiple
>   records in a Lightning Experience list view, those buttons take on new
>   life. 
> Watch your reps’ productivity soar when they click a button
>   to perform a custom mass action on several records at once.
> This
>   feature is available in both Lightning Experience and Salesforce
>   Classic.